# groupby does not return anything

Tags: mongodb-query

I am new to mongodb and I have the following db:

```
/* 0 */
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("546fca4bbadc0f7939048d76"),
     "name" : "ali",
     "time" : "20141105230000",
     "entity" : [ 
      1, 
      3, 
      4
   ],
"count" : 10
}

 /* 1 */
   {
        "_id" : ObjectId("546fca91badc8a4a144cfd8e"),
        "name" : "ali",
        "time" : "20141105231200",
       "entity" : [ 
      1, 
      3
    ],
     "count" : 10
     }
```

Now I want to groupby all by name and return he sum of count :

I have the following code but it does not return anything:

```
 DBCollection coll=db.getCollection("test");
     DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$name");
      DBCursor  cur=coll.find(groupFields);
      while(cur.hasNext()){
          System.out.println(cur.next());
```

Can anyone help how I can do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `$sum` function to the `$group` stage to get the sum of counts per group. And you can't simply fire a find query. You need to perform an aggregation  operation to get the results.

```
  DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$name");
  groupFields.put("sum", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", "$count"));
  DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);

  List<DBObject> pipeline = Arrays.asList(group);
  AggregationOutput output = coll.aggregate(pipeline);

  for (DBObject result : output.results()) {
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

I request you to go through the docs for more info, try till you can't ever find a solution then ask it on stackoverflow. That's how you will improve. It is just a suggestion. :http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-aggregation-framework-with-java-driver/

Comment: Thank you BatScream, I tried what you said but I get the following error : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.DBCollection.aggregate(Ljava/util/List;)Lcom/mongodb/AggregationOutput;

Comment: What version of the driver jar you are using?

Comment: If you mean mongo I use 2.10

Comment: now I changed it to 2.12.4 and it works thanks a lot